# Wordpress: Custom Post Type Editor on a page and saving it

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a little problem with a simple Wordpress task.
I have a custom post type, with its own editor. And the task is to put this edtior ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9mv4.png)) on an extra page as a formular for users to fill it out and save it as this post type. If is needed the user can edit it later in their overview.

At this moment I have the idea of using shortcodes and use the code for the editor but I can't save it, as this type.

I hope you guys can help me.
I have no other idea.